# Minified HTML <head> on Magento Product Page?

Tags: php, magento

For some reason my Product Page on a LOCAL Magento installation appears to be minifying? This subsequently breaks that page, mainly jQuery..

All other pages are fine - including catalog & CMS Pages / Home etc..

If you look here at the source for a category page:
[image: normal looking source code]

Then this is the source for a product page:
[image: broken product page html head]

What is causing this to happen? Any ideas? I am not using compression or minification as this a development environment.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think it's being minified it looks from the images like your product section of catalog.xml is not picking up the default includes from page.xml.  Try replacing those two with default catalog.xml and product.xml from another theme and removing local.xml to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment - I reverted back to the default catalog.xml in base/default/layout and I am still experiencing the 'minification' of the <head> section. There are no css/js files missing they are all in there but I am getting a JS error - I think that the 'minification' is causing this as this is the only page that is doing the above. Cheers

Comment: did you delete cache by clicking flush magento cache button after you reverted back?

Comment: Cache is turned off completely as is development environment - I have double checked this and still having the same issue.

Comment: ok I suggest, make sure that merging js is off from admin,  make sure any other plugin for minifying is turned off, then check if it works, if not, then check page.xml and catalog.xml, maybe you can paste the relevant part.  also turn on logging, create file exception.log and system.log check if there is any issue reported there after trying to run product page again.

Comment: Hello merging is off anyway... this is a development environment running on my Mac locally using SVN. All other pages do not product that 'minification' at the top - just the product page.

Comment: Can you post the HTML source as text rather than images? Unless there is more code beyond the end of the `title` tag this is not "minification", it's just missing javascripts. You stated this is a local development environment, does it work in your production environment? I would replace your catalog.xml and local.xml with the production version as @rabmcnab suggested. Are you using 3rd party modules for SEO on product pages or anything like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your comments, it turns out Better Configurable Products was the culprit for this, have disabled the module and it works now.